# Multiple using of % pattern within the same target rule in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Let's say there are a number of rules like this:

```
prefix/FOO/FOO_suffix/FOO.txt: prefix/FOO/FOO_input.txt
    echo @<
prefix/BAR/BAR_suffix/BAR.txt: prefix/BAR/BAR_input.txt
    echo @<
```

Instead of that I would like to have a single implicit rule like:

```
prefix/%/%_suffix/%.txt: prefix/%/%_input.txt
    echo @*
```

(So, the `%` represents the same <word>)
Is it possible to achieve that without using *foreach/eval/call/define* functions and generating explicit rules for each <word>?

Comment: Short answer: no. Make doesn't support the use of multiple wildcards in one implicit rule. There may be a way to get the same effect that doesn't use *foreach/eval/call/define,* but it'll be about as ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU make's secondary expansion can sometimes be used instead of `foreach-eval-call`:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

prefix/%.txt: prefix/$$(notdir $$*)/$$(notdir $$*)_input.txt
    @echo '$<'
```

Demo:

```sh
$ make prefix/FOO/FOO_suffix/FOO.txt prefix/BAR/BAR_suffix/BAR.txt
prefix/FOO/FOO_input.txt
prefix/BAR/BAR_input.txt
```

But if the reason you do not want to use `foreach-eval-call` is that you find the double expansion difficult to understand and maintain, secondary expansion is maybe not that simpler. Compare:

```
MY_MACRO = prefix/$1/$1_suffix/$1.txt: prefix/$1/$1_input.txt

$(foreach t,FOO BAR,$(eval $(call MY_MACRO,$t)))

%.txt:
    @echo '$<'
```

See? Not even a single `define` or `$$`...